# Count observations over rolling 30 day window

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rolling-computation, windowing

I need to create a variable that counts the number of observations that have occurred in the last 30 days for each id.

For example, imagine an observation that occurs on 1/2/2021 (d / m / y) for the id "a". If this observation is the first between 1/1/2021 and 1/2/2021 for the id "a" the variable must give 1. If it is the second, 2, etc.

Here is a larger example:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,  ~q,   ~date,
  "a",   1,   "01/01/2021",
  "a",   1,   "01/01/2021",
  "a",   1,   "21/01/2021",
  "a",   1,   "21/01/2021",
  "a",   1,   "12/02/2021",
  "a",   1,   "12/02/2021",
  "a",   1,   "12/02/2021",
  "a",   1,   "12/02/2021",
  "b",   1,   "02/02/2021",
  "b",   1,   "02/02/2021",
  "b",   1,   "22/02/2021",
  "b",   1,   "22/02/2021",
  "b",   1,   "13/03/2021",
  "b",   1,   "13/03/2021",
  "b",   1,   "13/03/2021",
  "b",   1,   "13/03/2021")
dat$date <- lubridate::dmy(dat$date)
```

The result should be:

```
id  q   date    newvar
a   1   01/01/2021  1
a   1   01/01/2021  2
a   1   21/01/2021  3
a   1   21/01/2021  4
a   1   12/02/2021  3
a   1   12/02/2021  4
a   1   12/02/2021  5
a   1   12/02/2021  6
b   1   02/02/2021  1
b   1   02/02/2021  2
b   1   22/02/2021  3
b   1   22/02/2021  4
b   1   13/03/2021  3
b   1   13/03/2021  4
b   1   13/03/2021  5
b   1   13/03/2021  6
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't quite understand the algorithm.  I thought it was giving a sequence of increasing integers by id and date, but then you've got the 12/02/2021 for observations "a" going from 3-6 instead of 1-4.  How do we figure out at what value the sequence is supposed to start?

Comment: Hi, because the observations 12/02/2021 for "a" counts the number of observations in "a" between 12/01/2021 and 12/02/2021 (30 days). So, two obs in 21/01/2021 should be considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sapply` and `between`, count the number of observations prior to the current observation that are within 30 days.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = sapply(seq(length(date)), 
                         function(x) sum(between(date[1:x], date[x] - days(30), date[x]))))

# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
   id        q date       newvar
   <chr> <dbl> <date>      <int>
 1 a         1 2021-01-01      1
 2 a         1 2021-01-01      2
 3 a         1 2021-01-21      3
 4 a         1 2021-01-21      4
 5 a         1 2021-02-12      3
 6 a         1 2021-02-12      4
 7 a         1 2021-02-12      5
 8 a         1 2021-02-12      6
 9 b         1 2021-02-02      1
10 b         1 2021-02-02      2
11 b         1 2021-02-22      3
12 b         1 2021-02-22      4
13 b         1 2021-03-13      3
14 b         1 2021-03-13      4
15 b         1 2021-03-13      5
16 b         1 2021-03-13      6
```

Answer (score 3):

Left join dat to itself on the indicated condition grouping by the rows of the left hand data frame. We assume that you want a 30 day window ending at current row but if you wanted 30 days ago (31 day window) then change 29 to 30.  Both give the same result for this data.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, count(b.date) as newvar
  from dat a left join dat b
  on a.id = b.id and b.date between a.date - 29 and a.date and b.rowid <= a.rowid
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   id q       date        newvar
1   a 1 2021-01-01             1
2   a 1 2021-01-01             2
3   a 1 2021-01-21             3
4   a 1 2021-01-21             4
5   a 1 2021-02-12             3
6   a 1 2021-02-12             4
7   a 1 2021-02-12             5
8   a 1 2021-02-12             6
9   b 1 2021-02-02             1
10  b 1 2021-02-02             2
11  b 1 2021-02-22             3
12  b 1 2021-02-22             4
13  b 1 2021-03-13             3
14  b 1 2021-03-13             4
15  b 1 2021-03-13             5
16  b 1 2021-03-13             6
```

To write it in a pipeline using [.] to denote the input data frame works.

```
dat %>% { 
  sqldf("select a.*, count(b.date) as newvar
    from [.] a left join [.] b
      on a.id = b.id and b.date between a.date - 29 and a.date and b.rowid <= a.rowid
    group by a.rowid")
  }
```

This runs roughly twice as fast as sapply on the data in the question.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  sqldf = sqldf("select a.*, count(b.date) as newvar
    from dat a left join dat b
    on a.id = b.id and b.date between a.date - 29 and a.date and b.rowid <= a.rowid
    group by a.rowid"),
  sapply = dat %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(newvar = sapply(seq(length(date)), 
                         function(x) sum(between(date[1:x], date[x] - days(30), date[x]))))
)
```

giving:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
  sqldf 26.2768 26.77340 27.97039 27.0082 27.29515  63.1032   100  a 
 sapply 42.8800 43.69345 48.53094 44.1089 45.25275 285.4861   100   b
```